# Why does wget ignore the query string in the URL?

Tags: shell, command-line, wget

I want to use wget to download the following 18 HTML files:

```
http://www.ted.com/talks/quick-list?sort=date&order=desc&page=18
http://www.ted.com/talks/quick-list?sort=date&order=desc&page=17
...
http://www.ted.com/talks/quick-list?sort=date&order=desc&page=1
```

No matter what comes after `page=`, it always downloads the first page of the listing. Do I have to escape some characters in the URLs? How?

Comment: Have you tried this ? http://www.ted.com/talks/quick-list?sort=date&desc&page=17

Comment: Are you doing `wget "http://www.ted.com/talks/quick-list?sort=date&order=desc&page=18"` or not using the double-quotes?

Comment: @rgbimbochamp I'd give it a try. Is there an explanation why should that fix the problem though?

Comment: @hrbrmstr ahh! so I should wrap the whole url in double quotations? I'll try that.

Comment: `&` is a special character in most shell environments, so it never makes it to `wget` as it executes the call in the background. If this works, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @hrbrmstr yes indeed. It worked, please add your answer.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`&` is a special character in most shell environments. You can use double quotes to quote the URL to pass the whole thing in as the parameter to `wget`:

```
wget "http://www.ted.com/talks/quick-list?sort=date&order=desc&page=18"
```

Comment: How would you use the {1..20} to download a range of files using a string?

Answer (score 5):

1. Store your list of URLs in a file (each URL in a separate line!!):

   `echo "http://www.ted.com/talks/quick-list?sort=date&order=desc&page=18
   http://www.ted.com/talks/quick-list?sort=date&order=desc&page=17
   ...
   " > wget_filelist.txt`
2. Call wget to retrieve the stuff:

   `wget -i wget_filelist.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Special case: There is still a problem with `wget "URL"` format, even though it solved the problem of `&` it can't pass `!` symbol.

Solution: Single quote instead of double quote for the URL will fix this, example:

```
wget 'https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-G.798-201712-I!!PDF-E&type=items'
```

As shown in above example, it works for me which contains both `&` and `!` symbols in it. I am not sure if it's an excepted solution for all platform (ie., official POSIX shell).

Bonus: Further we can use `wget -c 'URL'`, so that, in case there is a failure in one go and we don't need to start from beginning.